# show entire Book Navigation tree

Tags: 8, nodes, blocks

My question is about how to show the entire book navigation tree in a block (drupal 8)

Thanks to @oknate [we can have a Book Navigation block with the top level book showing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220458/10759), But i need the whole tree. (think table of contents)

*All the folowing examples assume you are are the top page of a 3 level deep book.*

**Also, I have a working module at https://github.com/petergus/alt-book-nav.git**

Showing the title (top level) book in the book navigation block is done by replacing the following in book/src/Plugin/Block/BookNavigationBlock.php (with a custom module of course)

```
 // Only show the block if the user has view access for the top-level node.
  if ($nid) {
    $tree = $this->bookManager->bookTreeAllData($node->book['bid'], $node->book);
    // There should only be one element at the top level.
    $data = array_shift($tree);
    $below = $this->bookManager->bookTreeOutput($data['below']);
    if (!empty($below)) {
      return $below;
    }
  }
```

with

```
     if ($nid) {
        $tree = $this->bookManager->bookTreeAllData($node->book['bid'], $node->book);
        return $this->bookManager->bookTreeOutput($tree);
      }
```

That only shows the top level and child level though, I want to be able to view the full tree from any page.

I am completely new with drupal 8 and not very handy with PHP so all i could find out was that

```
     $tree = $this->bookManager->bookTreeAllData($node->book['bid'], $node->book);
     kint($tree);
```

returns only the book name and first level
and

```
     $tree = $this->bookManager->bookTreeAllData($node->book['bid']);
     kint($tree);
```

(without the `$node->book`) returns multiples levels, that is, multiple 'below' arrays.

[image]

I have no idea how to go further with pulling that information into the block, does someone?

As mentioned above, I have the module that @oknate suggested at https://github.com/petergus/alt-book-nav.git

Greatly appreciating any help, and hoping this questions serves the community.

Answer (score 1):

It turns that I already posted the answer in the question, but somehow missed it during testing!

Removing `, $node->book` from `$tree = $this->bookManager->bookTreeAllData($node->book['bid'], $node->book);` does print the entire expanded tree.

If someone has time to [add a user form option](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-form-to-the-block-configuration) to the [module](https://github.com/petergus/alt-book-nav.git) it could eventually benefit many and get on the drupal.org repo.